# Vue list doesn't "properly" re-render after being sorted

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js

The sorting logic below is pretty simple:
1. Tags products that doesn't contain selected sorting value
2. Sort products by the amount of selected sorting value in descending order
3. Hide products that doesn't contain selected sorting value

I've added simple sorting logic and it does the trick to sort the elements (can be expected in the console)

**Current problem:**
The way the list is rendered to the page doesn't actually display newly order, but rather modifies order just of the few items.

**Actual code in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bohdanafanasyev/pen/wbVJEM?editors=0011)**

Can somebody suggest what can be a more efficient way to achieve functionality which will also properly "reposition" elements on the page according to the newly sorting order.

P.S: If you would select `iron` for example it will be visible that output in the console doesn't match with list items order rendered to the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `products` property which you are iterating in your html code to render the list of products is not an observable. Vue only tracks observable properties and re renders every time any one of the observables changes. Even though you are changing the order of products, Vue is not aware of the change as it is not an observable. To make `products` property an observable add it in data property just the way you have added nutrients and initialise it as an empty array.

Make your data field something like this:

```
data: {
  nutrients: nutrients,
  products: []
}
```

See [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) for better understanding of Vue's reactivity system works.

Comment: thank you a lot for the help and for pointing out this concept :)